# Will reducing number of includes/requires increase performance?

Tags: php, performance

What is better practice for script performance tuning?

This one?

```
require_once("db.php");

if (!is_cached()) {
  require_once("somefile.php");
  require_once("somefile2.php");
  //do something
} else {
  //display something
}
```

Or this one?

```
require_once("db.php");
require_once("somefile.php");
require_once("somefile2.php");

if (!is_cached()) {
  //do something
} else {
  //display something
}
```

Is it worth placing includes/requires into flow control structures or no?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will increase performance and contrary to what others said, the impact may not be negligible.

When you include/require files, PHP will check all the defined include_paths until it finds the file or there is nothing more to check. Depending on the amount of include pathes and the amount of files to include, this will have a serious impact on your application, especially when including each and every file up front. Lazy including (like in your first example) or - even better - [using the Autoloader is advisable.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)

Related reading that addresses this in more details:

- [Zend Framework Performance Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html)`*`

<sup>`*`The advice given there is applicable to any application or framework</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using autoloading in my applications, but exactly this application can't use autoloading because it have too much third party classes using rather strange class naming. :(

Comment: @Kirzilla you could consider setting up a custom fallback autoloader that has a list of classes to files `("ThirdPartyPieChartClass" => "/tools/piecharts/index.php")` etc., and loads the desired file, instead of including them all at once.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very good. As far as I understand, you mean I have to make a list of exceptions and then just do something like `if (isset($exceptions[$classname])) { require_once($exceptions[$classname]) } `? And of course before including/requiring check if classname already exists.

Comment: @Kirzilla yup (Sorry @Gordon for hijacking your answer :) That code would belong in your autoloader somewhere. I don't know what your current autoloader looks like. In Zend Framework, this would be a "fallback autoloader" that gets triggered if no class file could be found in the regular name spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Includes and requires are designed in part to allow you to organize your code and make maintaining your software easier to do. While there technically is a performance hit for using includes it is negligible and more then offset by increasing the maintainability of your software. Especially if you use an opcode cache. I wouldn't worry about this and chalk it up to premature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

It can sometimes be worth it if the required files are huge, and no byte code cache is available.

The issue then, however, is not really the number of `include()` statements, but the amount of data that gets included. The less unused code you include in a request, the better. 
A good remedy to monolithic includes is splitting the code base into smaller ones, or, if your application is largely object oriented, using PHP's [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) feature.

I've seen shared hosting packages where un-tangling monolithic includes could save up to *half a second* - which is a *lot*.

Also, included PHP code gets parsed and takes up memory, whether it's executed or not. A clean structure with lean objects is usually the optimal way.

Comment: I have eAccelerator enabled on server

Comment: @Kirzilla then I would do some profiling to find out how much can be gained.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will increase performance, but it is very very little so it isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute paths for include files will increase performance significantly. Test using Apache Benchmark to see if it doesn't.

Comment: Yup, that's why I have only one path in include_path